# Which of the following sentences is written correctly? "...while being in your house" or "... while you are in your house"?

Tags: grammar

In the context of: if you were to receive something. Ex. A package or groceries.

Ex. 1. You can get your groceries while being in your house.

Ex. 2. You can get your groceries while you are in your house.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct because 
"while" is a preposition in the first sentence, and a conjunction in the second one.
Though the second sentence is [preferable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=While%20being%20in%2Cwhile%20you%20are%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhile%20being%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhile%20you%20are%20in%3B%2Cc0) and less formal.

1. For [example](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&tbm=bks&q=inauthor:%22Jack%20Kyte%22&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizgrL41tbhAhUOpIsKHeRfAYUQ9AgIMTAC&biw=360&bih=668&dpr=3) :

"You are not allowed to write anything on any piece of paper other than your notebook while you are in the laboratory."

2. For [example](https://books.google.ru/books?id=NTSXBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT43&dq=%22while%20being%20in%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil6Le61dbhAhVyAhAIHXdkAZk4ChC7BTAHegQIARAr):

"I wondered why would they have on scuba diving outfits while being in a building?"